# A pending suggested edit can earn 2 rep after earning edit privilege (Just a factoid)

Tags: discussion, reputation

This is just a factoid that might be of interest to others, not really a topic for discussion (though it is plausible someone might want to comment on the subject). It appears that if one suggests edits before earning the privilege to directly make edits but earns enough reputation to gain that privilege before all of those edits are reviewed, then any suggested edits pending approval will earn 2 reputation points if approved.

(From an implementation perspective, this makes sense; checking the suggested edit queue whenever someone earns the edit privilege and applying without further approval any pending suggestions from that user would add complexity for little if any benefit. From a certain rule-oriented perspective, one would have to treat such suggestions as earning the reputation at the time of the suggestion rather than at the time of approval, when the reputation is actually awarded.)

I discovered this when I suggested two edits when my reputation was 999 (1000 on a Beta site earns the edit privilege). (I *am* happy that both edits were approved as I was concerned that they may have been too extensive.)

[This answer to "Is there a restriction on the number of suggested edits?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202449/226495) indicates that the suggested edit queue is the only limit on the number of edits that can be pending, so *in theory* on a slow day here at Writers one could use all 200 of the suggested edit queue slots and earn 400 reputation from suggested edits *after* earning the edit privilege from some other source.

(Of course, clogging the queue like that would show poor etiquette even if all of the suggested edits were good. Such a burst of edits would also show poor etiquette since edits bump questions to the top of the active list. Posting that many suggestions in a short time period would be possible but seem to require **significant** preparation.)

---

By the way, I used new tags ([suggested-edits](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggested-edits) and [privileges](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privileges)) which *are* tags on Meta Stack Exchange. I was surprised that they were not already present as default tags.

Comment: Heh, that's interesting.  Thanks for writing this up, and congrats on crossing 1k!